# Invalid property value error for calc() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

`<App>` has `<Header>` and `<Content>` components. I am trying to calculate height of `<Content>`  ie (App height - header height).

// App.js

```js
import { useStyles } from "./AppStyles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Header from "./Header";
import Content from "./Content";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { root } = classes;

  return (
    <Box className={root}>
      <Header />
      <Content />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

// AppStyles.js

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: "100vh" // <App> height
  },
  heading: {
    border: "1px solid blue",
    height: "4rem" // Height for <content>
  },
  content: {
    border: "1px solid green",
    height: `calc(100vh-4rem)`, // Invalid property value
    overflowY: "auto"
  }
}));
```

`height: "calc(100vh-4rem)"`
is not working and giving error ie `Invalid property value`.

// Content.js

```
import { useStyles } from "./AppStyles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { content } = classes;

  return (
    <Typography className={content}>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id varius
      sem. Aliquam aliquam leo quis turpis hendrerit dapibus. Mauris ullamcorper
      luctus faucibus. In consectetur, massa at sollicitudin facilisis, velit
      ..
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

// Header.js

```js
import { useStyles } from "./AppStyles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { heading } = classes;

  return <Typography className={heading}>header</Typography>;
}
```

`height: "calc(100vh-4rem)"`
is not working and giving error ie `Invalid property value`. How to fix this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/calc-function-usage-in-mui-sofl-sz7787) demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values inside calc() must be seperated by a  space.

```
height: "calc(100vh - 4rem)"
```